# How do bigger applications deal with potential (web)socket port clashes?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket

I'm writing a websocket connection between a chrome plugin and a desktop application that exclusively talk to each other locally. I know that you can't have two sockets listening on the same port (is this true for all ports?)

Port clashes won't happen for the majority of my users, but the application will run on a few thousand computers; I think I can reasonably expect there to be clashes in rare situations, where another application already occupies the port.

How do bigger applications deal with this potential issue? I'm fairly unfamiliar with networking and (web)socket programming in general.

I guess there are a few non-technical workarounds like these:

1. Log the issue well, and let support deal with it
2. Let the user configure a port

But I'd rather have a sound technical way to deal with it, if possible. I could come up with some algorithm that tries a few preconfigured ports, but I expect that this is a fairly well known problem in the industry, and am hoping to learn what the consensus is for this problem.

The question is primarily technology agnostic, but if it matters, my stack is python with [this websockets library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on the desktop side, and of course JavaScript on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a reason to overthink it. A list of seemingly un[occupied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) fallback ports and finally a prompt to specify a port should be fine. If both parties are capable of HDD IO (I don't know how much can a chrome plugin can do), then it's even easier for the plugin and the app to meet.

For two apps on a same host, you may also add an additional loopback interface. [Example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface).

If to speak about large networks, there's a class of so-called *service discovery protocols* that may help dealing with this kind of issue. Basically they are IP- or UDP-based multicast protocols that advertise different services across the network. Usually these protocols have a standardized port for communications, so it is unlikely to get occupied by another app. Examples are DHCP, Bonjour.

However, dealing with port conflicts are not their primary function. In large networks machines should be under some sort of control and should not have lots of apps grabbing random ports. If a conflict happens with third party apps, the ideal solution is to look for a setting that allows to set ports manually.

Comment: I suppose the best option would be to use define two or three arbitrary open ports that both the client and server know about then. It's simple. If it ever were to happen that a port conflict happens regardless, I'll just let support deal with it. Sounds fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know how bigger applications actually do it but a way could be to try till you find a free port?

```
found_port = False
ports = [port1, port2, port3 ....]
for port in ports
    try:
        mySocket.bind ( ( ip_address, port ) )
        found_port = True   
   except:
        pass
   if found_port:
       break
```

Comment: There are some hairy implications here, the client side needs to know what socket the server side is trying to listen for, right? I know I don't know a lot about network programming, so I'm explicitly trying to avoid finding a solution like this myself.

Comment: Yes thank you :). To account for that i have added a ports_list in the answer, a client could also try to connect over the ports list